# How to disable "text-selection" cursor in RichEdit

Tags: c++, winapi, richedit

I want to show standard "pointer" cursor instead of "text-selection cursor" (shown in the picture below) in RichEdit:

[image]

The only way I see now is to intercept `WM_SETCURSOR` message in my window, determine wether cursor is inside RichEdit control, and replace it with "normal" cursor. Besides it's not so cool, I want to keep a "hand" cursor, which appears when cursor points to a link.

Is there an easier method?

**UPDATE:** Some clarifications for comments:

1. @Remy Lebeau. Actually I just want to display text with some formatting abilities: automatic words wrapping, different colors for some symbols inside the same text, hyperlinks, and may be - displaying images. And I want to get this text from the internet, display this text in a single control, also it's quitу comfortable to create such a text in RTF-editor, like WordPad. However the information shown in RichEdit is not intended to be edited or copied, and app design looks better without "text-selection" cursor. So, I think that RichEdit is what I need. But, of course, you can suggest something else.
2. @Jeaninez. I have already set the `ES_READONLY` property, it does not affect neither cursor, nor selection (the latter I solved by intercepting the `EN_SELCHANGE`  notifications).
3. @Barmak Shemirani. Yes, I can process hyperlinks. Here is the code snippet I use now to handle cursor changing:

```
    // This method processes the WM_SETCURSOR message.
    LRESULT MainWindow::OnSetCursor(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        auto h = (HWND)wParam;
        if (h == richEditHwnd) {
            return TRUE; // Prevents cursor changes by next processors
        }
        return DefWindowProc(mainWindowHandle, WM_SETCURSOR, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:** As Barmak Shemirani pointed out in comment, the `ENLINK` notification may be caused by mouse events, so now I have almost working solution (however I don't understand exactly how it works):

The `WM_SETCURSOR` handler:

```
LRESULT MainWindow::OnSetCursor(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    auto h = (HWND)(wParam);
    if (rich.hwnd == h) {
        if (HIWORD(lParam) == WM_MOUSEMOVE || HIWORD(lParam) == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || HIWORD(lParam)== WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK) {
            DefWindowProc(windowHandle, WM_SETCURSOR, wParam, lParam);
            auto cursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
            SetClassLongPtr(rich.hwnd, GCLP_HCURSOR, (LONG_PTR)cursor);
            return true;
        }
    }                

    return DefWindowProc(windowHandle, WM_SETCURSOR, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The `EM_LINK` notification handler:

```
    auto enLink = (ENLINK*)lParam;
    if (enLink->msg == WM_LBUTTONUP) {
        std::wstring linkId(enLink->chrg.cpMax - enLink->chrg.cpMin, L'0');
        TEXTRANGE textRange{enLink->chrg, (LPTSTR)linkId.data()};
        SendMessage(nmHeader->hwndFrom, EM_GETTEXTRANGE, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&textRange));
        ProcessLinkClick(enLink, linkId);
    }
    else if (enLink->msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE || enLink->msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK || enLink->msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        auto cursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND);
        SetClassLongPtr(enLink->nmhdr.hwndFrom, GCLP_HCURSOR, (LONG_PTR)cursor);
        return TRUE;
    }

    return 0;
```

This code works properly for `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` LPARAM arguments, but fails on `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` argument.

**UPDATE 3:** It seems that I rushed with previous code - it somehow blocks the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message for `EM_LINK` notification, so I cann't properly handle clicks on link.

Comment: Why do you want this? Displaying a text cursor when the mouse is over a text input field is standard UI behavior, and is what users expect. Why do you want to change that?

Comment: Maybe you want to add the style `ES_READONLY`. It would make sense to have the hand cursor over hyperlink in a read-only richedit control. Have you managed hyperlink redirection yet? I should be a similar method. Show the code, or at least part of the code that you are using.

Comment: According to your description, whether you want to make the richedit not to select? If so , I suggest you could try to use [EM_SETREADONLY message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setreadonly) to set the read-only style of the edit control.

Comment: Commenters are not notified when you put @user in the question. I meant what do you have in `WM_NOTIFY`

Answer (score 0):

***This is a comment, it doesn't answer the question***

Don't override `WM_SETCURSOR`, let RichEdit handle it and "*Hand*" cursor should show automatically for hyperlinks.

You can override the cursor and force it to use the "*Arrow*" cursor. But richedit will no longer show the "*Hand*" cursor for hyperlinks (because of the override) This override can be done as follows:

```
hcursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW));
...
case WM_SETCURSOR:
{
    if (hrichedit == (HWND)wparam) { SetCursor(hcursor); return TRUE; }
    break;
}
```

Otherwise we have to find out when mouse is over hyperlink. I don't know how to do that smoothly.

In theory we can catch `WM_NOTIFY` messages for mousemove, when we go in/out of the link, but I had trouble getting that right.

Comment: I downgraded this answer to a comment!